# JavaScript ASp.net.. error in Storing Value in HiddenField from JavaScript.. Check Code below

Tags: asp.net

My Try 1:

```
var a=confirm('Do You Really want to Save this Record?') ;
document.getElementById('Hidden.ClientID') = a;
```

My Try 2:

```
var a=confirm('Do You Really want to Save this Record?') ;
document.getElementById('Hidden.ClientID').value = a;
```

Code Behind :

```
Response.Write(Hidden.Value);
Response.End();
```

//////////
Why Value is Not getting stored in Hidden Field?

Comment: provide more code  that accessing hiddin field and how are you using hidden field..

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
var ele=document.getElementById('<%=Hidden.ClientID%>');
ele.value=a;
```

Comment: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Comment: Ok.. Error GOne.. but Still Value not getting Stored..

Shows me Blank Value as its "" at Design time

Answer (score 2):

Working Code see

```
document.getElementById('<%=Hidden.ClientID%>').value="a";

    Code Behind :        
    Response.Write(Hidden.Value);
    Response.End();
```